# "Session expired" error while logging in with Selenium IE Webdriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, session, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a suit of test, that were successfully run with Firefox driver for Selenium and Chrome one.
While logging in to app, test types correct credentials (Tried to login with the same credentials and everything`s ok) and clicks on submit button.
Then session expired error appears.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I tried to clear cache and cookies. Nothing helped.

Comment: What happens when you perform the same steps manually, on the CI server, using the IE?